# what does it mean by __attribute__((__aligned__(PAGE_SIZE)))?

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel

I am dealing with a Linux device driver project, in that i encountered with this:

```
__attribute__((aligned(PAGE_SIZE)))
```

I Think the above one is a specific use of `__attribute__`.

I couldn't find satisfactory answers. I need to know, What does `__attribute__` means, and the use of the same

Answer (score 2):

It is used to specify that a variable or a `struct` should have a specific alignment in memory. Read about it [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html).

Basically in your example it forces whatever has that attribute to be aligned to a memory page (`PAGE_SIZE` is just a numeric constant). The `__attribute__` keyword is used to specify certain special things, `aligned` is just one of many.